# WordPress Injected Files Producing Spam

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently found that my self-hosted WordPress site had been gate-crashed.

Some evil *son-of-a-motherless-goat* had injected two PHP files, `ini.php` and `post.php` into the root directory. This resulted in my server sending truck loads of spam to the rest of the world.

I have since taken the whole thing off line and deleted the offending files, and this has resolved the issue. A backup from before the event is helping me to reconstruct the blog, but I’m doing it without WordPress this time.

The question is how could these files have been injected? Is it a known weakness with WordPress or a weakness in my own security? None of my other sites has been invaded this way, and I’m usually careful about these things.

I know that it’s impossible to be sure what happened in this case, but I would appreciate some suggestions as to what might have happened.

Comment: See the [Wordpress FAQ](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked). Your question is off topic here, you can consider asking on [wordpress.se] or [webmaster.se].

Comment: @GeraldSchneider this question will also be off topic on [wordpress.se]. Recovering from hacks needs full hands on with the site. I really do not think that questions regarding hack recoveries fits the scope of any SE site. It is just way too involved

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hacked sites really needs full hands on attention which cannot be handled here

Comment: @GeraldSchneider This is not specifically something which the WordPress FAQ addresses, and it’s not the point. I am asking whether it’s a known hole in WordPress or whether I needed to have secured it otherwise.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I am not trying to recover from the hack, since I have already done so. I am asking whether this is the result of a known weakness in WordPress or of something else. Perhaps asking on Sever Fault might have given me some clues, but I suspect that there may be an issue with a PHP script which might have been involved.

Comment: Any language can and will be hacked at some stage, but if you are running the latest PHP and Wordpress version, you should be relatively safe. there are a million and one places where hackers can find loopholes. The easiest places are URL's and form fields. So you would need to make sure that if you use GET variables or have any type of user input, that you escape, sanitize and validate any incoming data before use. Loopholes are also not always in a plugin, theme or platform, it can be on your hosts side as well. so all in all, this still stays very broad

Answer (score 1):

A wordpress installation normally get hacked if you have outdated plugins or core files keeping these updated is crucial! Besides that you could take other security mesures like only having your active theme and only having your active plugins in other word delete everything you dont use on your site.

Comment: All fully up to date before I took the site down completely.

Comment: Well it can happen to any site updated or not but updating your site prevents a lot of it

Comment: Other security measures could be chaning /wp-admin to something else and only having one admin account

Answer (score 0):

Little things you can do to prevent it happening again are:

1. Remove readme.html from the WordPres root directry as it gives what version you are running
2. Ensure PHP errors aren't outputted - this can be changed by updating your php.ini, but most shared hosting platforms should do this by default - the errors can tell the user what version of apache/ngnix/php you are running

Comment: Hiding the readme.html is really pointless.  For a start it will keep appearing every time you upgrade but it's very easy to find the Wordpress version number without it. Here are two old-but-good articles on it -> http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/20/the-wordpress-meta-generator-tag-paranoia/  && http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/20/the-wordpress-meta-generator-tag-paranoia/